# Не могу удалить python

Tags: python, python-3.x, install

при попытке удалить python появляется ошибка. Удалял через приложения в windows. Перегуглил всё что мог, но так ничего и не помогло.(version: 3.10.7)  log: https://drive.google.com/file/d/15TXzj50xcB8gO_CjS7hh0SKCcsIplGzP/view?usp=share_link

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Информативная часть лога, видимо, имеющая отношение к ошибке:

```
Applying execute package: path_JustForMe, action: Uninstall, path: (null), arguments: ' ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" MSIFASTINSTALL="7" TARGETDIR="C:\Users\Костьян\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310" OPTIONALFEATURESREGISTRYKEY="Software\Python\PythonCore\3.10\InstalledFeatures"'
Error 0x80070643: Failed to uninstall MSI package.
Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-user MSI package.
Applied execute package: path_JustForMe, result: 0x80070643, restart: None
Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
```

Comment: Ну выложите куда-нибудь этот `log file`. Ну или попытайтесь из него что-то значимое извлечь. Возможно, там не только про эту установку написано, опять же, выкиньте лишнее.

Comment: хорошо, я вставил ссылку на лог

Comment: Пробовали от администратора запускать деинсталляцию? Я добавил в вопрос ту часть лога, которая по-моему основная для разбора ошибки.

Comment: я тоже посмотрел логи до этого, но забыл добавить, что по этому пути нет такого файла

Comment: по поводу деинсталляции, уже попробовал, не помогло

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, благодаря вам я проверил логи(а точнее в первой строчке написан путь где находится файл для деинсталяции питона) лучше и починил и удалил его и теперь смотрю и понимаю что у меня ещё осталась папка с питоном, теперь я просто её удалил )

Comment: У меня это решилось тем, что я установил python по тому пути, который python мне предлагал установить изначально

Answer (score 0, accepted):

path: C:\Users\Костьян\AppData\Local\Package Cache{c62ef944-a7c9-4646-9fc7-d9e658defc1f} я перешёл по этому пути и там был файл пайтон который мог и чинить и удалять пайтон, сначала я его починил, а потом удалил, как то так )

Answer (score 0):

Нажмите WIN + R, в открывшемся окне введите AppData, идите по пути Loca -> Programs. И удаляете папку Python или зайдите в эту папку и удалите нужную вам версию.